# При клике на ссылку и переходе на другую страницу, переходить на нужную вкладку (tabs)

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт вкладок (табов), приведу его ниже. Переходы по вкладкам работают при помощи `onclick=""`. Подскажите, как сделать, что бы при клике по ссылке на любой странице сайта (на страницу с нашими табами) автоматически открывалась, например третья вкладка? У меня есть кнопка внутри первого таба, она работает, переключает, но не понимаю как быть, когда кнопка находиться на другой странице сайта.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(cityName + "-tab").classList.add("active");
  // evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("London-tab").click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button id="London-tab" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button id="Paris-tab" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button id="Tokyo-tab" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  <button class="new-btn" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Click Me</button>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: что значит "на другой странице сайта"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Например табы у меня на странице  /blog/, а ссылка стоит на странице /contacts/.

Comment: Ничего не ясно)) как это вы хотите с другой страницы кликнуть табы на другой странице)) из разряда фантастики.

Comment: А я надеялась, что есть варианты )

Comment: Варианты есть....Но может быть в вопросе не ясно описано что именно под этим понимается. Может быть страницы перезагружаются, а может меняются через ajax, а может это всё одна страница и просто блоки "выше/ниже" на странице, а может открыта одна вкладка в браузере и другая и нужно их взаимодествие....... просто в вашем конкретном случае при описанной ситуации не ясно зачем это вообще надо

Comment: У меня есть посты про Лондон, Париж, Токио. И на сайте будут ссылки "Посмотреть все записи про Токио". И когда нажимаешь, переходишь на страницу с табами и там уже открыта вкладка Токио.

Comment: Можно через хэш добавить, а нужную вкладку открывать с помощью javascript, считывая значение хэша.

Comment: @АннаМатвеева ↑↑↑ только не знаю что имелось в виду под хэшом, скорее достаточно открыть страницу с GET параметром. А javascript'ом считать этот GET и в зависимости от заданного значения открывать нужную вкладку

Answer (score 0):

Вот простейший вариант табов на чистом CSS.
Такой вариант как раз будет открывать нужный таб на другой странице при переходе туда, читая хеш в url. Нужно лишь к ссылке на новую страницу добавить id нужного таба.

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tabs-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  order: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.tabs-links>a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabs-links>a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.tabs>#tab-1:target~.tabs-links>a[href="#tab-1"],
.tabs>#tab-2:target~.tabs-links>a[href="#tab-2"],
.tabs>#tab-3:target~.tabs-links>a[href="#tab-3"] {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: default;
}

.tabs>div:not(.tabs-links) {
  display: none;
  order: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.tabs>div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div id="tab-1">
    Первый таб.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2">
    Второй таб..
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3">
    Третий таб...
  </div>

  <div class="tabs-links">
    <a href="#tab-1">Таб 1</a>
    <a href="#tab-2">Таб 2</a>
    <a href="#tab-3">Таб 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению не подойдет. Там еще много функционала завязано, помимо табов. Мне надо использовать именно те табы (

Comment: Допишите в url ссылки хеш (#tokyo например), и напишите простой скрипт читающий url страницы (window.location.href), который будет доставать хеш и добавлять active к нужному табу.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.